# Why does OverBar treat the number 90 differently?

Tags: output-formatting

Why does this `OverBar[#]& /@ Range[85, 95]` return a list, all of whose members except 90 have overbars? Does `OverBar[90]` have special meaning?

Comment: I get overbars over all, including 90, on 13.0.1 on Mac, as well as 12.2.0 on Raspberry Pi. Note that `OverBar /@ Range[85, 95]` does the same thing: you don't need `[#]&`.

Comment: Does `? OverBar` reveal anything? Or ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[OverBar]``?

Comment: Cannot replicate on v12.2.0 Win7-x64. Please include `$Version` info.

Comment: Try restarting Mathematica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OverBar` is not `Protected`, so

```
OverBar[90] = "?"
OverBar /@ Range[85, 95]
```

yields

[image]

I'd guess you did something like `OverBar[90]=90`.